# "We will not only go to Mars but also to Jupiter." is grammatically correct? And some other questions

Tags: parallelism

Is this grammatically correct?

> 1. "We will not only go to Mars but also to Jupiter."

How about

> 2. "We will go not only to Mars but also to Jupiter."

and

> 3. "We will go to not only Mars but also Jupiter."

I believe the first sentence violates parallel structure and the second and third stick to parallel structure. However some native speakers told me the first sentence is okay but others are not. I'd like to know which sentence(s) is right or not and why. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: All are grammatical. The first instance has a *go* elided before the second *to*, so it works.

Comment: (2) is best from a strictly logical point of view, but all are understandable.